# Ruby: Lightweight web server

Tags: ruby, webserver, light

I'm developing at Ruby on Rails. It's good framework and etc., but now I need to make one little promo-site. It can be done at simple HTML, but should have content at two languages.
It will be very pretty if I can use some super-fast and lightweight framework. Something like Ruby on Rails, with ERB-templates, partials and YAML-files for internationalisation, but without ActiveRecord and blah-blah-blah. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the website can be done using static HTML, but you want the comfort of templates and YAML internationalization, you might want to take a look at [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), which does exactly that. :)

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Middleman is based on Sinatra, and appears to be exactly what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Sinatra? Renee? These are the small frameworks that are great for this kind of job.

Answer (score 0):

[Mini-rails](https://github.com/gmarik/mini-rails) can also be a good solution to your problem, especially if your website might grow one day or another